# Is there a way to automate Android OS testing (not just the apps)?

Tags: android, automation, appium

Preface:

I'm working with small company that make its own devices with custom flavored Android OS (eBooks and one model of smartphone). I have the experience of browser, API and mobile apps (iOS | Android) automation.

Problem:

But today i've heard the idea from my manager. He offered me to find tool or just a way to automate Android OS testing, not just the apps. He said that if i will find a way to do that, i will save pretty much of time for company.

Of course i have a lack of knowlege about custom Android OS architecture (my job was only to make automation), but right now i'm stuck with the answer. The only tools that possibly could be used with more than just 1 app is Appium.

Please tell me if this even possible thing to automate testing of your own Android OS version?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

So how i see it:

1. We are on the main screen of our smartphone OS.
2. There is a clock widget on the main screen.
3. Without physical contact and human involved, the system makes imitation of "long touch" on the clock widget
4. Small menu with a list of options appears.

Comment: What exactly does "automate Android OS testing, not just the apps" mean? I recommend that you edit your question and provide a few examples of what exactly you are trying to test. After all, a lot of "Android OS" *is* "just the apps", which can be tested using UiAutomator and kin.

Comment: Thank you, i've added sample scenario of test.

Comment: UiAutomator should be able to handle that, though I have not tried it with home screen app widgets: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after more research and comment of CommonsWare (thank you!) i have found the answer.

What i needed is testing **system apps** and **cross app testing**. Android Support Library have a tool for that - it's called UIAutomator. This one feels absolutely nice while being on home screen and around - clicking elements, finding them and simulating hardware buttons.

If you face this problem once upon a time - just use this thing.

Comment: can you please clarify what is meant by cross app testing

Comment: It's testing functionality of multiple applications during one test. Like you send e-mail through you gmail app to get technical support and go to app you are testing to check if your technical support ticket was created.

Comment: Thanks, did you discover any other additional techniques apart from the ways mentioned in the answer. It would be helpful if you could share them.